# Python 3 BeautifulSoup with regex returns None

Tags: python-3.x, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting BeautifulSoup with regex to work. I have tested the regex and it seems to work but BeautifulSoup still returns None.

Example of code I want to find

```
body class="page-template-default page page-id-1864
```

My code:

```
 element = soup.find(text=re.compile(r"((body class).*.(page-id-\d+))"))
```

I have also tried with just the below and it still returns None

```
element = soup.find(text=re.compile(r"(body class)"))
```

I can confirm that the section is part of the `response.content`

Comment: The page is probably loaded dynamically, pleas share the URL

Comment: I don't think that's the issue as the content is inside response.content. The content I want to get can be found on any Wordpress site. For example https://crimestoppervic.com.au/

Comment: The `text=` searches for specific text. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the text from body class to page-id (as per regex)

Comment: What would be an expected out here?

Comment: To get the content starting from body class until page-id-\d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
data = """
    <body class="home page-template-default page page-id-10 original wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-6.4.1 vc_responsive" data-footer-reveal="false" data-footer-reveal-shadow="none" data-header-format="default" data-body-border="off" data-boxed-style="" data-header-breakpoint="1000" data-dropdown-style="minimal" data-cae="linear" data-cad="650" data-megamenu-width="contained" data-aie="none" data-ls="none" data-apte="standard" data-hhun="0" data-fancy-form-rcs="default" data-form-style="default" data-form-submit="default" data-is="minimal" data-button-style="default" data-user-account-button="false" data-flex-cols="true" data-col-gap="default" data-header-inherit-rc="false" data-header-search="false" data-animated-anchors="false" data-ajax-transitions="false" data-full-width-header="false" data-slide-out-widget-area="true" data-slide-out-widget-area-style="slide-out-from-right" data-user-set-ocm="off" data-loading-animation="none" data-bg-header="false" data-responsive="1" data-ext-responsive="true" data-header-resize="1" data-header-color="custom" data-transparent-header="false" data-cart="false" data-remove-m-parallax="" data-remove-m-video-bgs="" data-m-animate="0" data-force-header-trans-color="light" data-smooth-scrolling="0" data-permanent-transparent="false" cz-shortcut-listen="true">...</body>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

Find `body` and get its `class`, slice to get first 4 classes:

```
classText = soup.find('body').attrs['class'][:4]
```

Convert `list` to `string` and `slice` the last characters:

```
' '.join(map(str, classText))[:-2]
```

**Output:**

```
'home page-template-default page page-id-'
```

Not bulletproof, but with that little context.